# How to compare two strings in C++

Tags: c++

Lets say I have string a and string b
I know I have to use a.equals(b) to compare two strings but in C++, it looks like I can directly use if(a==b)..., and I also found that string has a compare() fuction, so which one should I use, == or compare()

Comment: if (str1.compare(str2) == 0)
    std::cout << "Both String are equal".

Answer (score 2):

use `==` when you want to test for equality. It call `str1.operator ==(str2)`

Use `std::string::compare` if you want to know whether string is less than, equal to or greater than other string. `std::string::compare` returns a negative number (if str1 is lexicographycally or in dictionary order less than str2), 0 or a positive number accordingly. (analogous to str1 - str2)