# Can't compare two strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, compare

I am facig some problems with my code in c++. It seems like I cant compare strings use the if operator. This is my code:

```
//correct creds
std::string uname ("admin");
std::string pass ("password");

//input creds
std::string r_uname;
std::string r_pass;

//ui
printf("%s \n", "Please enter username");
scanf("%s", r_uname);
printf("%s \n", "Please enter password");
scanf("%s", r_pass);

//cred check
if((r_uname == uname) && (r_pass == pass)){
    printf("%s", "You are in");
}
else{
    printf("%s", "Wrong username/password");
}
```

libraries included: stdio.h and string

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `scanf()` and `printf()` instead of `std::cout` and `std::cin` in `c++`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two strings in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120218/how-to-compare-two-strings-in-c)

Comment: The comparison is ok, but `scanf` just doesn't work with C++ classes like `std::string`.

Comment: The program exhibits undefined behavior.  `scanf` knows nothing about `std::string`, and who knows what damage scanf is doing to the `string` object.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't think that's a duplicate

Comment: @PasserBy: Then don't vote to close it as one. Pick one of the others you can find with *[c++] compare two strings* in a site search here.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `C++`, the default is to use `std::cout` and `std::cin` from `iostream` unless you have a good reason not to.

In your case, you are using `scanf()` to read the user input. `scanf()` can only read into a `C` styled string AKA `char arrays`. I don't think your code will even compile in most compilers because you pass in `std::string`. Moreover, you are comparing `C` styled strings which just compares the memory addresses of the beginning of the arrays. You should be using `strcmp()` to compare `C` strings.

Here is how you use C++ to compare strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //correct creds
    std::string uname ("admin");
    std::string pass ("password");

    //input creds
    std::string r_uname;
    std::string r_pass;

    std::cout << "Enter username: " << std::endl;
    cin >> r_uname;

    std:: cout << "Enter password: " << std::endl;
    cin >> r_pass;

    //cred check
    if ((r_uname == uname) && (r_pass == pass)){    
        std::cout << "You're in!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Wrong credentials" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to use string in C++, you should use cin or cout instead of scanf or printf.
To use cin in C++, you need to include

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
*#include <iostream>*

int main(){
  //correct creds
  std::string uname ("admin");
  std::string pass ("password");

  //input creds
  std::string r_uname;
  std::string r_pass;

  //ui
  printf("%s \n", "Please enter username");
  //scanf("%s", r_uname);
  *std::cin >> r_uname;*
  printf("%s \n", "Please enter password");
  //scanf("%s", r_pass);
  *std::cin >> r_pass;*

  //cred check
  if((r_uname == uname) && (r_pass == pass)){
      printf("%s", "You are in");
  }
  else{
      printf("%s", "Wrong username/password");
  }

}
```